# My python code runs in the terminal but not in blender?

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

SERVER.py:

```
import sys
import os
import socket
import threading                                           #new
import random
import Crypto
import pickle
from collections import namedtuple
from Crypto.Hash import MD5
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto import Random
import ast

passwordDict = {'Gauri':'Chitale','Aditya':'Guru','Shaili':'Shah','Rohit':'Jindal'}

def main():
    host = 'localhost'
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.bind((host, 5000))
    server.listen(5)
    print ('Waiting for partner to join conversation...\n')
    (conn, client_addr) = server.accept()
    print ('client connected from address:',client_addr)
    communicate  = Communicate(conn)
    communicate.run()

    print('Communication terminated \n')
    try:
        conn.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
        conn.close()
    except:
        # connection already closed
        pass

    return 0

class Communicate:
    def __init__(self, conn):
        self.conn = conn

    def run(self):
        """
        Invoked when new thread is executed
        """
        print ('inside run')
        self.read()

    def read(self):
        """
        Responsible for reading in data from the client and displaying stdout
        """
        print('inside read')
        random_generator = Random.new().read

        key = RSA.generate(1024,random_generator)
        publickey = key.publickey() # pub key export for exchange

        self.conn.send(pickle.dumps(publickey))
        #public key sent

    #receive data from client
        temp  = self.conn.recv(1024)
        print (temp)
        encdata  = pickle.loads(temp)
        print (encdata)
        uspa = key.decrypt(encdata)
        print (uspa)
        uspa = uspa.decode('utf-8')
        uspa = uspa.split(',')
        userid = uspa[0]
        print (userid)
        password = uspa[1]
        print (password)
        hexval = uspa[2]
        print (hexval)
        hexval = str(hexval)
        try:
            m= MD5.new()
            d = userid+password
            d = d.encode('utf-8')
            m.update(d)
            k = m.hexdigest()
            print (k)
            if k == hexval:
                sendpass = passwordDict[userid]
                print (sendpass)
                if sendpass == password:
                    answer = "allowed"
                else:
                    answer = "unauthentic_user"
            else:
                answer = "unauthentic_user"
        except:
            answer = "wrong_user"
        print ('answer:',answer)
        answer = bytearray(answer,'utf-8')
        self.conn.send(answer)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

CLIENT.py:

```
import sys
import os
import socket
import threading
import random             #new
import fractions
import pickle
#import bge
import Crypto
from collections import namedtuple
from Crypto.Hash import MD5
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto import Random

def main():
    host = 'localhost'
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client.connect((host, 5000))

    comm = Communicate(client)
    comm.run()
    return 0

class Communicate:
    def __init__(self, conn):
        self.conn = conn

    def run(self):
        """
        Invoked when new thread is executed
        """
        self.write()

    def write(self):
        #sendname = bge.logic.globalDict["user"]
        #password = bge.logic.globalDict["pass"]
        sendname = 'Gauri'      
        password = 'Chitale'
    # receive server public key
        receive = self.conn.recv(1024) 
        pubkey = pickle.loads(receive)

    #send data
        data = sendname+password
        data = data.encode('utf-8')
        h = MD5.new()
        h.update(data)
        digest = h.hexdigest()
        digest = str(digest)
        tosend = sendname+','+password+','+digest
        print(tosend)
        cipher = pubkey.encrypt(tosend.encode('utf-8'),32)
        self.conn.send(pickle.dumps(cipher))



        result = self.conn.recv(1024)
        result = result.decode('utf-8')
        print ('result:',result)
        if result == "allowed":
            print("allowed")
        else:
            print("notallowed")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question: never, ever, use a bare `except:` clause. For more info see [The Little Book of Python Anti-patterns](http://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/no_exception_type_specified.html).

Answer (score 1):

In BGE, `__name__` is never equal to `__main__` so your client is never getting run. (Or are you running it in module mode?) More details/blend files would be useful.

BGE requires scripts to be non-blocking - they run inside a single frame. You haven't got any reads yet, but this may catch you out later.

Comment: I assumed he calls "main" from Python controller in module mode. I guess you are right, if you know how module mode works you would never include a __main__ check as it is not necessary